# 2D array script for retail

Tags: vba

I have a script that takes manager names in `Sheets("Mgrs")` and extracts the employees that fall under each manager in `Sheets("Retail Sharepoint File-Merge")`. Once it finds the managers employees, it prints the array to a new worksheet and formats it and saves it based on the values I lay out.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Retail_Cuts()
    Dim j As Long, k As Long, x As Long
    Dim varArray() As Variant
    Dim varArray2() As Variant
    ReDim varArray(1 To 19, 1 To 1)

    Dim strManager As String, strEC As String, strLogin As String
    Dim BASEPATH As String, strNewPath As String, strFileName As String
    Dim Wb As Workbook

    Dim mgrRow As Long
    Dim colManager As Long
    colManager = 3

    Dim colLogin As Long
    colLogin = 4

    Dim colEC As Long
    colEC = 5

    BASEPATH = "M:\11-19-2018\"

Call Ludicrous(True)

    For mgrRow = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mgrs").UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mgrs").Cells(mgrRow, 1) <> "" Then
            strManager = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mgrs").Cells(mgrRow, 1)

            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Retail Sharepoint File-Merge")
                ReDim varArray(1 To UBound(varArray, 1), 1 To 1)
                x = 1
                For k = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
                    varArray(k, x) = .Cells(1, k)
                Next
                For j = 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
                    If strManager = .Cells(j, colManager) Then
                        x = x + 1
                        ReDim Preserve varArray(1 To UBound(varArray, 1), 1 To x)
                        For k = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
                            If k = 1 Then
                                varArray(1, x) = CStr(Format(.Cells(j, k), "000000000"))
                            Else
                                varArray(k, x) = .Cells(j, k)
                            End If
                            strEC = .Cells(j, colEC)
                            strManager = .Cells(j, colManager)
                            strLogin = .Cells(j, colLogin)
                        Next
                    End If
                Next
            End With

            strNewPath = BASEPATH & strEC & "\"
            If Len(Dir(strNewPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                MkDir strNewPath
            End If

            strFileName = strLogin & " - " & strManager & " - " & "Shift Differential Validation" & ".xlsx"

            ReDim varArray2(1 To UBound(varArray, 2), 1 To UBound(varArray, 1))

            Set Wb = Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet)
            With Wb
                With .Worksheets("Sheet1")
                    .Columns(1).NumberFormat = "@"
                    .Columns(15).NumberFormat = "0%"
                    .Columns(18).NumberFormat = "0%"

                    For j = 1 To UBound(varArray, 2)
                        For k = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
                            varArray2(j, k) = varArray(k, j)
                        Next
                    Next

                    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(varArray, 2), UBound(varArray, 1))) = varArray2

                        .Columns("N:O").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                        .Columns("Q:Q").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
                        .Columns("R:R").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                        .Columns("S:S").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

                        Call DataValidation
                        Call Header
                        Call Macro1

                        .Range("C2").Select
                         ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True

                        .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
                        .Rows("1:1").Font.Bold = True

                        Call protect

               End With

                .SaveAs strNewPath & strFileName, Password:="ShiftDiff", FileFormat:=51
                .Saved = True
                .Close

            End With
            Set Wb = Nothing
        End If
    Next

Call Ludicrous(False)

    End Sub
```

The only problem is that it takes about 1-1.2 seconds to create, save, password protect, format, create two data validation lists, etc... Is this something I need to just deal with or is there a way to speed up these things? The `Call Modules` aren't much code at all, so the bulk of the improvements would be done in the code.

I have turned off all calculations, screen updates, etc... under the `Ludicrous Mode` moniker.

Is there a way to speed up the saving/password protecting? I know if you use a `CopyAs` save function into a template, that speeds it up a TON, but then you can't password protect. Any thoughts?

Comment: Saving is I/O bound, the bottleneck is your hard drive, or the network you're saving the file onto ...not the code.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: You could `FileCopy` the template and then use an `ADODB.Connection` to insert the records.

Answer (score 1):

1. Performance measurement

"The only problem is that it takes about 1-1.2 seconds to create, save, password protect, format, create two data validation lists, etc"

Which portion of this 1000 to 1200 milliseconds corresponds to data retrieval? which one to formatting ranges or to saving? Try setting multiple timers each for a different task.

2. Variables and naming scheme

Perhaps this has nothing to do with performance, however, it affects the readability and appreciation of your algorithm. I see hard-coded variables like:

```
Dim BASEPATH As String: BASEPATH = "M:\11-19-2018\"
```

Consider using constants:

```
Const BASEPATH As String = "M:\11-19-2018\"
Const colManager = 3, colLogin As Long = 4, colEC As Long = 5
```

Consider using self-explanatory names. Insead of i, j, k, varArray() varArray2 etc, I would rather use:
iRow, iColm, iField, iRecord, iManager, iEmployee.
vManagers(), vManagers_trans(), the latter being the transpose of the former

3. Code simplification and efficiency

Instead of reffering frequently to the upper bound of 1st dimension, which is constant throughout the procedure, one may fix it like this:

```
Const NbFields As Integer = 19
Dim varArray() As Variant: ReDim varArray(1 To NbFields, 1 To 1)
```

For this line:

```
For j = 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
```

What is the point in retrieving data below the UsedRange? By definition, it's not USED, hence has no datum to get from.

I'm not sure how helpful are these assignments:

```
strEC = .Cells(j, colEC)
strManager = .Cells(j, colManager)
strLogin = .Cells(j, colLogin)
```

These strings will be overwritten by the next iteration. Only those of the last iteration will SURVIVE!

For the following loop:

```
For k = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
    varArray(k, x) = .Cells(1, k)
Next
```

I think it may be replaced by one assignment:

```
   varArray() = .Cells(1,1).Resize(1, NbFields).Value2
```

Even the If-Else may be optimized, so instead of:

```
For k = 1 To UBound(varArray, 1)
    If k = 1 Then
       varArray(1, x) = CStr(Format(.Cells(j, k), ...
    Else
       varArray(k, x) = .Cells(j, k)
    End If
```

why not simplifying things:

```
varArray(1, 1) = CStr(Format(.Cells(j, 1), ...
For k = 2 To NbFields
    varArray(k, x) = .Cells(j, k)
```

As you can see, reaping that conditional expression (j * k) times is an unnecessary overhead.